Need help implementing a strategy for backtesting,py
Background: I am trying to backtest a strategy in which I buy or sell based on the breakout of a given time period. The strategy follows this plan: The highs and lows made between 8 PM and 12 AM are mapped out. If the high is breached, a long position is triggered; if the low is breached, a short position is triggered. Each trade risks 1% of the account balance, with a stop loss of 20 pips and a take profit of 40 pips.
Problem: The issue I am facing is that when I try to backtest the code, it does not trigger any trades. Additionally, certain backtesting.py metrics, such as the Sharpe ratio, display as NaN.
the code is below
Custom Strategy Class
class HighLowBreakout(Strategy):
account_size = 1000  # Starting account size in GBP
risk_per_trade = 0.01  # 1% risk per trade
def init(self):
    self.high_mark = None
    self.low_mark = None

def next(self):
    current_time = self.data.index[-1].time()  # Correctly access the time of the current bar
    if time(20, 0) <= current_time <= time(23, 59):
        # During 8 PM to 12 AM, calculate highs and lows for the session
        session_data = self.data.df.loc[(self.data.df.index.time >= time(20, 0)) & (self.data.df.index.time <= time(23, 59))]
        self.high_mark = session_data['High'].max()
        self.low_mark = session_data['Low'].min()

    elif time(0, 0) <= current_time < time(6, 0):
        # After 12 AM, check for breaches and place trades
        if self.high_mark and self.data['High'][-1] > self.high_mark and not self.position:
            self.enter_trade(is_long=True)
        elif self.low_mark and self.data['Low'][-1] < self.low_mark and not self.position:
            self.enter_trade(is_long=False)

    elif current_time == time(18, 0):
        # Close all positions at 6 PM
        self.position.close()

def enter_trade(self, is_long):
    """
    Enter a trade with proper risk management.
    :param is_long: True for long position, False for short position.
    """
    stop_loss = 20 / 10000  # 20 pips stop loss
    take_profit = 40 / 10000  # 40 pips take profit
    account_risk = self.account_size * self.risk_per_trade
    trade_size = account_risk / stop_loss  # Units of currency to trade

    if is_long:
        self.buy(size=trade_size, sl=self.data['Close'][-1] - stop_loss, tp=self.data['Close'][-1] + take_profit)
    else:
        self.sell(size=trade_size, sl=self.data['Close'][-1] + stop_loss, tp=self.data['Close'][-1] - take_profit)

Im really new to coding, ive tired using Chatgpt to help and I cant seem to get any more progress. I think the issue is in this section of the code
def init(self):
    self.high_mark = None
    self.low_mark = None

def next(self):
    current_time = self.data.index[-1].time()  # Correctly access the time of the current bar
    if time(20, 0) <= current_time <= time(23, 59):
        # During 8 PM to 12 AM, calculate highs and lows for the session
        session_data = self.data.df.loc[(self.data.df.index.time >= time(20, 0)) & (self.data.df.index.time <= time(23, 59))]
        self.high_mark = session_data['High'].max()
        self.low_mark = session_data['Low'].min()

    elif time(0, 0) <= current_time < time(6, 0):
        # After 12 AM, check for breaches and place trades
        if self.high_mark and self.data['High'][-1] > self.high_mark and not self.position:
            self.enter_trade(is_long=True)
        elif self.low_mark and self.data['Low'][-1] < self.low_mark and not self.position:
            self.enter_trade(is_long=False)

    elif current_time == time(18, 0):
        # Close all positions at 6 PM
        self.position.close()

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I believe the problem i am having is that the code is not generating a buy or sell signal. based on the fact that some parts of backtesting.py summary is working I dont think the data is an issue my issue seems to be with the generation of a signal.
